# What are the localhost URLs for OpenShift hosted Django apps

Tags: django, openshift

I created a Django application locally and then using the django openshift template from 
[here](https://github.com/openshift/django-example) I uploaded it to OpenShift successfully. Now I'm trying to work on the local repository for adding additional features but when I run the server locally, I get a bad url error.
What I would like to know is how do I locally host a OpenShift Django App?
I also tried `rhc tail -a appname` but that only gets me a small amount of debug info If I can't locally host it then is there a way with which I can see the python `print()` output for the app hosted on OpenShift?

Comment: How are you running the server? What address are you using to access it?

Comment: I'm using a the development server that's provided by Django which listens to the loopback on 8000 for hosting it locally.

Comment: More specifics would have been helpful, but I assume you're running `manage.py runserver` and then accessing 127.0.0.1:8000. So, exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Exactly. I'm getting a Bad Request (400)